# Reading input of hardware keyboard within application

Tags: android, android-input-method, android-keypad, android-hardware

I want to know if there is any provision that allows me to read the input key from a hardware keyboard present on the phone or connected externally in android . I basically am building an application that needs to have special shortcuts set . I researched about the WindowManagerPolicy but eclipse does not seem to support any interface of that sort . I need help even starting .

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);    
}
```

override activity's onKeyDown to catch keyboard event

Comment: This dos not work for a hardware keyboard BTW . Its only for input from the virtual keyboard .